# Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage

Tags: hadoop, cloud, apache-pig, nosql

I am getting following error while running following pig script

```
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/avro.jar
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
REGISTER /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/pig/piggybank.jar
list_cookies = LOAD '/user/xyz/testbed/llama-2014-Oct-12d/abc'
    USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
```

got following error

```
2014-10-22 11:51:14,705 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.pig.builtin.AvroStorage
Details at logfile: /home/xyz/pig_1413991623605.log
```

Comment: Does your folder contain other data than the avro data? Is the schema provided in the folder?

Comment: abc is just single file

Comment: is it a huge file ? if it's not you can do `hadoop dfs -cat /user/xyz/testbed/llama-2014-Oct-12d/abc | head -1` to take a look at the schema

Comment: maybe it does not contain any schema and you need to provide the avsc file?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was simply the fact that the input folder did not exist. Pig error messages are off the mark and not at all helpful. After changing the input folder to one that existed, this error went away.  So, be sure to check that before spending a lot of time more difficult debugging!